# Selenium select element by class name

Tags: python, html, selenium

I got the html below from https://www.flashscore.com/football/ live section
[image]

How cam i get all the element of class event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine using python selenium ?

Comment: There are different types of elements `<div>`, `<img>`, `<svg>` within the `...class="event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine"...`. Which elements are you looking for? Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath's contains method. Like this:

`//div[contains(@class, 'event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine')]`

It returns all elements contain this classes.